# Date changes after added to ArrayList

Tags: java, object, for-loop

I have the following:

```
List<ArrayList<AvailablePeriodObj>> outputLists = new ArayList<ArrayList<AvailablePeriodObj>>();

ArrayList<AvailablePeriodObj> partOutputList = new ArrayList<AvailablePeriodObj>();    
DateTime beginCheck = periodsList.get(0).getStart();
DateTime endCheck = periodsList.get(0).getEnd();

for(int i= 0; i< periodsList.size(); i++) {
            AvailablePeriodObj apo = periodsList.get(i);

            if(apo.getStart().equals(beginCheck) && apo.getEnd().equals(endCheck)) { 
                partOutputList.add(apo);
            } else {
                outputLists.add(partOutputList);
                partOutputList.clear();
                beginCheck = apo.getStart();
                endCheck = apo.getEnd();
                partOutputList.add(apo);
            }
            if(i== (periodsList.size() - 1)){
                outputLists.add(partOutputList);
            }

        }
```

With this I am making new lists for all pairs of start and date, my problem is that after the process is completed every object in all the lists get the last used start and date value.

What I want as result is multiple ArraLists depending on how many different start-date pairs there are.

Comment: Could you please add some more detail about what you are trying to achieve here. It is not very clear.

Comment: Added some more details..

Comment: sorry, I think I misread the code. wrong answer. how are you creating the outputlists? we might need to see some of that code

Comment: The outputlist is a list of lists, its's created in the first rule\

Comment: where is the `periodsList` declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `partOutputList.clear();`  create a new `partOutputList` instance (`partOutputList = new ArrayList<AvailablePeriodObj>()`).

All you are doing right now is adding the same `partOutputList` instance to `outputLists`,  clearing it then adding the last values.